Unique solution of ODE with blow up
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times [0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function such that the ODE
$\mathrm{d} x(0) = f(x(t), t) \mathrm{d}t,\quad x(0) = x_0$
has a unique solution on $[0,1)$. The function $f$ could potentially blow up as $t \rightarrow 1^-$ and need not be Lipschitz. I would like to know if there are conditions on $f$ which guarantee that $\lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-} x(t)$ exists and is finite.
As an example where the limit exists despite $f$ blowing up as $t \rightarrow 1^-$ consider $f(x, t) = -x/(1-t)$. In this case the ODE is solved by $x(t)=(1-t)x_0$ for $t<1$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow 1^-}x(t)=0$.
Thanks!
